# Construir app de Angular a producción, no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy intentando crear una app en Angular 7, siguiendo el tutorial que te da por default la página

```
ng new my-app
```

Ya lo revisé con `ng serve --o` y funciona, pero no tengo idea ahora como pasarlo a un ambiente fuera de Angular. He hecho

```
ng --build --aot=true
```

Esto me ha creado una carpeta `/dist/my-app` y dentro vienen 3 archivos principales de JS: `main.js, polyfills.js y runtime.js` He abierto el `index.html` pero no se muestra nada, yo esperaba ver lo mismo que estaba haciendo en development.

He intentado correrlos con node, haciendo por ejemplo `node main.js` pero no me ha resultado, en las 3 opciones dice

> window is not defined

¿Alguien ya ha hecho estos deploys para ver como sería en producción?

Que estoy haciendo mal....

Comment: El contenido de build es html y javascript. Lo puedes poner en un servidor apache. Supongo que es normal que al abrir de manera directa el index.html no habrá nada ya que todo en Angular se genera a través de javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo generado en `dist/` es lo que debes exponer mediante un servidor http. No sirve abrir directamente el html con el browser.

Por ejemplo, usando [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve):

- Instalarlo global `npm install -g serve`
- `cd` hasta la carpeta con el `index.html`
- Ejecutar `serve`

Con esto, el servidor http expone una url en localhost que abre por defecto index.html y reconoce como resolver las referencias a recursos js en la carpeta correcta.

**EDIT**

Si bien lo anterior es cierto y aplica en general, muy problablemente simplemente abriendo el `index.html` funcionaria de no ser por lo siguiente que viene por defecto en proyectos con [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/application/files/src/index.html.template):

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Eso instruye al browser resolver las URLs relativas tomando en cuenta esa [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/base), en este caso *la raiz*

Comment: También puede instalar apache y jalar todo a la carpeta htdocs. Tomando en cuenta que lo quiere para producción.

Comment: @Angel exacto, sea cual sea el servidor http que utilice para produccion debe exponer la aplicacion como si fuese una pagina estatica. Mencione serve porque es un utilidad minimal que funciona con el mismo stack tecnologico que ya tiene instalado.

Comment: Que raro, por ejemplo moví los archivos a la raiz C:/ y funcionó, sin servidor, esto lo hice por que abrí la consola y vi que el browser por alguna razón desconocida está buscando todos los archivos ahí

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob la razon del porque necesitas un servidor http es esa. El browser ve que el index.html le pide el recurso `src="runtime.js"` una ruta relativa al dominio actual, ¿cual es ese dominio? `file:///` si lo abres asi como asi que probablemente en windows termine siendo igual a `C:`, en linux seria `/`

Comment: Exacto! Pero la ruta relativa es la carpeta contenedora, no C:/ digo, al momento que se construyó el `dist/my-app` y tratar de abrir el `index.html` la ruta relativa es donde estoy actualmente es decir `/my-app`, ¿Por qué va a buscarlos a C? de hecho cambié a `src="./runtime.js"` y de igual forma lo fue a buscar a C, sabes por qué pasa eso?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob tienes razon, he actualizado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando

```
npm run build --aot=true
```

Lo acabo de probar con Angular7 y funciono correctamente

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice, y me volvió a crear `dist/my-app` y dentro los mismos archivos, y me ha resultado lo mismo, abro el `index.html` y no muestra nada, donde tengo que correr este código?

Comment: ya probaste solo npm run build

Comment: Ya lo probé y sigue igual, no muestra nada. Construye de nuevo la carpeta dist, y los archivos que ya había comentado, pero no se como hacer para que se vea

Answer (score 0):

Hola para construir un app a producción debes correr el comando `ng build --prod` creara una rapeta llamada /dist y dentro venda todo construido, llevo un par de años usando este comando y nunca falla :)